# Proof verification of functions being the same almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, measurable-functions, almost-everywhere

Let ($X, \mathscr{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space and, $T:X \to X$  $\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{F}$ measurable map such that:
$\mu(C)=\mu(T^{-1}(C))$ for all $C\in \mathscr{F}$, and let $u\in\mathscr{L}^1(\mu).$

Prove that if $u \le u\circ T, \mu$
a.e. then $u=u\circ T \mu$ a.e..

My attempt:
We know the following: $\mu({u\gt u\circ T})=0$, by assumption.
We want show $\int |u \circ T-u|d\mu=0$ almost everywhere. Note that by assumption: $\int |u \circ T-u|d\mu=\int u \circ T-ud\mu= \int u 
\circ T d\mu-\int u d\mu=*$,

Since $T$ preserves the measure we get: $\int u\circ Td\mu=\int u d\mu$, hence:

$* = 0$. Thus $|u \circ T-u|=0, \mu$ a.e.. Conclusion: $u\circ T=u, \mu$ a.e.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: I think you are confusing what you want to prove with what you know. You want to prove that $u \geq u \circ T$ a.s. and you justify it by your knowledge of $u \leq u \circ T$ a.s. The second does not imply the first in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is not correct. 'This coresponds with ...'  does not make sense and you did not even make use of the fact that $T$ is measure preserving. Use the fact that $\int [u\circ T-u]=0$ because $\int u\circ T=\int u$ and $u\circ T-u$ is non-negative to conclude that $u\circ T=u$ a.e.

Comment: So it suffices to show that the integral of the difference is zero to prove that two functions are the same a.e.?

Comment: That works only because the function whose integral is $0$ is already given to be non-negaitve.  @Main